# When advertising a URL, should the leading https:// be included?

Tags: best-practice, presentation, web-standards

I realize this question belongs more on the [Digital Marketing Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65811/digital-marketing), but since that experimental SE was deleted, I'm dropping it here. Please forgive me.

I'm working on a flyer that has a URL, and I'm wondering whether or not to include the `https://` in the beginning. Does it add any sense of reassurance for a typical customer to know it's a "secure" URL? Or does it just get in the way visually and make the URL less memorable?

To be clear, it *is* an `https://` URL - I just want to know if it should be printed that way. Also, it is not simply the site name or brand, like "Twitter" or something you might type into a search engine and find. There is a specific `/path` that follows.

Please let me know what the trend is these days. I would have omitted `http://` back before the `s` was standard, but now that there is an aspect of security and trustworthiness to be weighed, I'd like to know how other designers are approaching this. I haven't been given any specific direction regarding how to present the URL. Thanks.

Comment: Personal opinion: I *never* include the http/https -- few consumers are cognizant of the s there.. many merely look for the lock icon in the browser if they are concerned. It's only those in the tech industry that are even aware of what the s means. In short, it's *not* a selling point to 90%+ of the public. -- and either way.. the browser will add the appropriate http prefix.

Comment: @Scott Those are all good points. I did a comparison with and without, and it looked much better without it. I will leave it off. Thanks for helping me decide.

Comment: @Scott You should make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal opinion:

I *never* include the `http`/`https` -- few consumers are cognizant of the `s` being there. Many merely look for the lock icon in the browser if they are concerned about security.

It's only those in the tech industry that may even be aware of what the `s` means.

In short, it's not a selling point for a *large* portion of the public.

....and either way.. the browser will add the appropriate http prefix.

---

For what it's worth.. I *also* leave off the `www` **if** it's not necessary - it's important to **test the URL** for this one. While many hosting providers will auto-redirect between www and non-www urls, not all will. So you should verify the correct page loads without the www before removing it from any url. This is unlike the `http`/`https` those are *always* added in every browser.